# How to print response data in pdf using pdfkit in node js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, pdf-generation, pdfkit

Using this function I am able to get data from mongoDb and pass to front end

```
function formfind(req,res){

    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");

    var query = req.body; 
    FormRecord.find(query).exec().then((r)=> {
        res.send({ 'data':r,'status' : true});
    }).catch((e) => {
        res.send({'status':false});
    });

}
```

How can able to print this data in pdf using pdfkit. My pdf function is

```
function pdf(req,res){

var pdf = require('pdfkit');
var fs = require('fs');

var doc = new pdf;

doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('node5.pdf'));
var query = req.body; //dynamic query based on input cheap for alpha version

    FormRecord.find(query).exec().then((r)=> {
        res.send({ 'data':r,'status' : true});
    }).catch((e) => {
        res.send({'status':false});
    });


  var loremIpsum = ' MEMO';  
  doc.fillColor('black')
  doc.font('Helvetica-Bold').text(loremIpsum, {

     paragraphGap: 30,
     indent: 20,
     align: 'center',
     underline: true
  });  

doc.moveDown()
  doc.text('1. District',{
  width: 550,
  indent: 20,
  align: 'left'
});

doc.moveDown()
  doc.text('2. Division',{
  width: 410,
  indent: 20,
  align: 'left'
});


//doc.rect(doc.x, 10, 500, doc.y).stroke()
doc.end();

}
```

I am able to get pdf using this function. I need to print the data also along with district and division in pdf.

How can I able to achieve the same.

My data using function formfind is

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "createdAt": "2018-03-15T14:38:47.552Z",
            "district": "sdhgb",
            "_id": "5aaa859a5719071130e96002",
            "_division": tyu
        }
    ],
    "status": true
}
```